# UA: didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler not being called when app is in background AND connected to Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, push-notification, fetch

I would like to implement (silent) remote notifications in my app,
note that I've already implemented regular push notifications.

Steps:

1. Enable background Capabilities in my project (remote notifications)
2. Add `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler`in my AppDelegate
3. Send push notification with Urban Airship* (`"content-available" = 1;)

*UA 3.03.

It only works when the app is active in the foreground.

Am I doing something wrong??

Thx

Comment: any update let us know?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the problem:

`"content-available" = 1` has to be inside `aps`

e.g.

`{"aps":{"alert":"Hi", "content-available":"1"},"device_tokens":["…"]}`

Comment: this will not push silent notification :( does that solve your problem ?